# Checking to see if a conversation already exists Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, message

Hey guys I'm building an eloquent query to see a conversation with an array of participants already exists. The reason for this is so we can't have the same conversation with same participants created more than once.

Here's my eloquent query:

```
$convos = Conversation::whereHas('participant', function ($query) use ($participantIds) {
                        $query->whereIn('user_id', $participantIds)
                        ->groupBy('convo_id')
                        ->havingRaw('COUNT(convo_id)='.count($participantIds));
           })->get();
```

$participantIds is equal to [1, 2] or [1, 2, 3] for example.

How do I check if a conversation exists with the id's in $participantIds? The above query will return a conversation that has **ANY** of the participants in the array

So if I have a conversation with John (2) and Matt (4) but try to make a conversation with just me and John this query will show I have a conversation with John already

Comment: can you post your DB scema for required tables

Comment: just want to see how Conversation and Users are related

Comment: Participant hasMany User, Conversation hasMany Participant, Message belongsToMany Conversation @jaysingkar